# Blender 2.81 Grease Pencil - Only some layers antialiased

Tags: grease-pencil, antialiasing

I'm working with Blender 2.81's Grease Pencil and am finding that only some layers render antialiased. I believe the problem is best illustrated with an example.

[image: Blender viewport]

In Blender's viewport, the drawing looks fine, and the lines rescale when zoomed just as any vector graphics should.

[image]

When rendered, however, as the image above shows, not everything is antialiased. The edge of the hair on the right side is part of a separate layer from the rest of the head, which leads me to believe that only certain layers are antialiased and the others aren't.

In this particular example, the layer with the foremost parts of the hair is the only layer that renders antialiased. It also happens to be the topmost layer, but I don't know whether that has any relation.

Does anyone know what could be causing certain layers to render antialiased and others to not? Is this a bug or expected behavior? Is the only solution to render at a higher resolution and sample down?

Comment: Same here, with 2.83alpha. Actually, I'm not getting any antialiasing at all, not in viewport nor in renders. Changing settings in `preferences > viewport > GP multisampling` don't seem to change anything.

Comment: It looks like Blender 2.83 has a large overhaul of the Grease Pencil drawing engine with a lot of bug fixes so hopefully these antialiasing issues are will be fixed when it releases.

Comment: Yep, can confirm that everything's fine now, my previous comment was from before the GP overhaul being merged in [2.83 experimental release](https://builder.blender.org/download/).